# How do I display the short URL from a Bitly API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm trying to add a query string to a URL, encode it, then shorten it using the Bitly API (**http://dev.bitly.com/api.html**).

The first two steps are working well and I have managed to send the URL to Bitly using the API but cannot display the short URL; all I'm seeing is `[object Object]`

I know that the API call has been successful as when I log in to my Bitly account I can see the  bitmark in my history so the problem must lie with my code and I'm sure it's something simple but sadly it's beyond me.

```
$('#shorten').click(function () {
        $encodedTrackedURL = encodeURIComponent($trackedURL);
        $bitly = $.getJSON('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=' + $accessToken + '&longUrl=' + $encodedTrackedURL + '&format=json');
        $('#displayURL').text($bitly);
    });
```

I have put the full code onto jsfiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/gstubbenhagen/EnNq3/15/**

P.S. OAuth access token is stored in the variable `$accessToken` but removed for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using `$.getJSON` correctly. Since that is an asynchronous call, the string is not stored in a variable synchronously. Instead, you need to do your follow-up work in a callback function.

```
$('#shorten').click(function () {
    $encodedTrackedURL = encodeURIComponent($trackedURL);
    var params = {
        access_token: $accessToken,
        longUrl: $encodedTrackedURL,
        format: 'json'
    };

    $.getJSON('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten', params, function (response, status_txt) {
        $('#displayURL').text(status_txt + ' ' + response.data.url);
    });
});
```

In addition, you'll want to take a closer look at the [documentation for `/v3/shorten`](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten) to understand the return value properly. Notice that it actually returns a JSON object, with the `url` value being the short URL. You can also specify `format: 'txt'` and get the short URL (in string form) as the entire response.

**EDIT**: I misunderstood the API docs. Looks like the response object contains metadata at the outer level (such as a bit.ly status text, not the same as the HTTP response text) and then an inner `data` object should contain the real data. I couldn't get it to work due to lacking an access token, but go ahead and try the above. ([Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnNq3/17/))

Comment: Thanks for this, I knew it would be something fairly obvious as this was my first stab at asynchronous. It seems to be working now but I cannot display the short url - I get 'undefined'. I can display the status however by using status_txt. Any ideas? 

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gstubbenhagen/EnNq3/16/

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the response object from the API docs. I'll edit.

Comment: Still getting 'undefined' for the short url. Oddly status_txt is showing 'success' rather than 'OK' which is what I was expecting to see from the API docs... ?

Comment: I've got it up and running using the the txt format but any pointers on getting the JSON format working would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry... I'm stumbling through just by reading the API docs, with no experience actually using the API. When I started my answer, I was mainly aiming to deal with the async issue, and it just kind of blossomed from there. Sorry! If I get a chance to play around and figure this out later, I'll edit my answer again. Glad you got it working for now, though!